# How to select by date entered by the user?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the below query to run an sql statement. It works fine. I wish to know how I can modify the query to select by a date which the user enters in ASP.NET. This means that I need to modify the part:

```
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = '02-AUG-2006'
```

Any ideas please?

The query I am using is this:

```
INSERT INTO TRANSACTION (TRX_UNIT, TRX_DATE, TRX_USR)
SELECT SOURCE_SYSTEM_CHANNEL_CODE, TRANSACTION_DATE, USER_CODE
FROM FCR_TRANSACTION
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = '02-AUG-2006'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about:

```
// Create a connection object and data adapter
MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

// Create a SQL command object
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO TRANSACTION (TRX_UNIT, TRX, TRX_USR) ";
cmdText += "SELECT SOURCE_SYSTEM_CHANNEL_CODE, TRANSACTION_DATE, USER_CODE ";
cmdText += "FROM FCR_TRANSACTION ";
cmdText += "WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = @TransactionDate";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnx);
cmd .Parameters.Add("@TransactionDate", YourDate); // <-- Insert date here
// Set the command type to text
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: +1 : First answer, and it has a parameterised query!  Wooooo! :)

Comment: of course, using something else is just stupid :). But I'm not sure it compiles though, but he should be using something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you must have a name for the date field where the user enters a date. let us say you decide to name it 'datename'
after that the $_POST("datename") returns the text entered in the field.
so now the WHERE statement becomes

```
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = '$_POST("datename")'
```

if that doesnt work, try

```
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = $_POST("datename")
```

all this is assuming you kept method of form transfer as POST....if you have it as GET, simply replace $_POST with $_GET here..

This should work. If it doesnt, my apologies.

Comment: Looks like PHP to me, not ASP.NET?

Comment: Also, always sanitize your DB inputs. I know it's example code but pulling raw values directly from server vars into SQL strings like that is very dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to query by the exact Date, you have to validate the Userinput, and add a parameter
to the query (this is only pseudocode) :

```
        string userInput = txtDate.Text;
        DateTime parsedDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(userInput, out parsedDate)) {
             // valid date, add a Parameter to your command
            var cmd = ... // create your DB Command here
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT .... WHERE Transaction_Date = @txDate";
            cmd .Parameters.Add("@txDate", parsedDate); 
            // execute your command ...
        }
```